# What is the problem with this flask app? i tried killing the process in that port and still its showing Bad Gateway 502

Tags: python-3.x, flask

This is the flask app i am trying to run. But when i try to access it using post 5000, it always shows 502 Bad gateway.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return 'Welcome to ABC Corporation'

@app.route('/')
def company_details():
    company_name = 'ABC Corporation'
    location = 'India'
    contact_detail = '999-999-9999'
    
    return f'''
    Company Name: {company_name}<br>
    Location: {location}<br>
    Contact Detail: {contact_detail}
    '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I tried killing the process in port 5000 and also tried with other ports, still couldnt solve the problem.

Comment: It works fine for me. How are you accessing the flask app?